# How can i setup connection timeout error in websocket?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, websocket

I am trying to toast a message if I don't get a response from a WebSocket connection but I am not able to figure out how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the message after some timeout:

- Start a timer when you send the request, which will display the message when this timer has finished
- Cancel the timer when the response comes.

You can not display a message if the response *never* comes, because you can not know if the response will eventually come any time later.